# Convert AWS SES received emails to human readable format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Is it possible to convert received emails in AWS SES to a human readable format before forwarding to SNS or S3? Please share a example code, if its possible.

A sample email content received is as follows

```
FW: Test Email 1\r\n\r\nTest 1\r\n\r\nFrom: Ashan \r\nSent: Friday, 
April 21, 2017 2:30 PM\r\nTo: ‘test@example.org' 
<test@example.org<mailto:t=\r\nest@example.org>>\r\nSubject: Test 
Email\r\n\r\nHi,\r\n\r\nThis is a test 
mail.\r\n\r\nRegards,\r\nAshan\r\n\r\n--
_000_HK2PR0302MB2609710D3BC86E413C88D359B81A0HK2P2MB2609_\r\nContent-
Type: text/html; charset=\"us-ascii\"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 
quoted-printable\r\n\r\n<html xmlns:v=3D\"urn:schemas-microsoft-
com:vml\" xmlns:o=3D\"urn:schemas-micr=\r\nosoft-com:office:office\" 
xmlns:w=3D\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\"
    =\r\nxmlns:m=3D\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml\" 
xmlns=3D\"http:=\r\n//www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta 
http-equiv=3D\"Content-Type\" content=3D\"text/html; charset=3Dus-
ascii\"=\r\n>\r\n<meta name=3D\"Generator\" content=3D\"Microsoft Word 
15 (filtered medium)\">\r\n<style><!--\r\n/* Font Definitions
    */\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:\"Cambria Math\";\r\n\tpanose-
1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-
family:Calibri;\r\n\tpanose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}\r\n/* Style 
Definitions */\r\np.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, 
div.MsoNormal\r\n\t{margin:0in;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:.0001pt;\r\n\tfont-
size:11.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;}\r\na:link, 
span.MsoHyperlink\r\n\t{mso-style-
priority:99;\r\n\tcolor:#0563C1;\r\n\ttext-
decoration:underline;}\r\na:visited, 
span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed\r\n\t{mso-style-
priority:99;\r\n\tcolor:#954F72;\r\n\ttext-
decoration:underline;}\r\np.msonormal0, li.msonormal0, 
div.msonormal0\r\n\t{mso-style-name:msonormal;\r\n\tmso-margin-top-
alt:auto;\r\n\tmargin-right:0in;\r\n\tmso-margin-bottom-
alt:auto;\r\n\tmargin-left:0in;\r\n\tfont-size:12.0pt;\r\n\tfont-
family:\"Times New Roman\",serif;}\r\nspan.EmailStyle18\r\n\t{mso-
style-type:personal;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-
serif;\r\n\tcolor:windowtext;}\r\nspan.EmailStyle19\r\n\t{mso-style-
type:personal;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-
serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D;}\r\nspan.EmailStyle20\r\n\t{mso-style-
type:personal;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-
serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D;}\r\nspan.EmailStyle21\r\n\t{mso-style-
type:personal;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-
serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D;}\r\nspan.EmailStyle22\r\n\t{mso-style-
type:personal-reply;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-
serif;\r\n\tcolor:#1F497D;}\r\n.MsoChpDefault\r\n\t{mso-style-
type:export-only;\r\n\tfont-size:10.0pt;}\r\n@page 
WordSection1\r\n\t{size:8.5in 11.0in;\r\n\tmargin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in
    1.0in;}\r\ndiv.WordSection1\r\n\t{page:WordSection1;}\r\n-->
</style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>\r\n<o:shapedefaults v:ext=3D\"edit\" 
spidmax=3D\"1026\" />\r\n</xml><!--><!--[if gte mso 9]>
<xml>\r\n<o:shapelayout v:ext=3D\"edit\">\r\n<o:idmap v:ext=3D\"edit\" 
data=3D\"1\" />\r\n</o:shapelayout></xml><!-->\r\n</head>\r\n<body 
lang=3D\"EN-US\" link=3D\"#0563C1\" vlink=3D\"#954F72\">\r\n<div 
class=3D\"WordSection1\">\r\n<p class=3D\"MsoNormal\"><span 
style=3D\"color:#1F497D\">Test 4 - </span><span
    =\r\nstyle=3D\"color:#1F497D\"><a
```

The textual content of the email expected was 'Hi, this is a test mail'

Comment: Please show an example of an email you would like to convert. Also, please show a sample of the code you have tried so far and let us know what difficulties you have encountered. For tips on asking a question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @John If you setup the above basic steps, ses email received -> sns or s3 by default aws gives it in a raw format, icluding encoded characters & etc. I would like to convert the body to simple textual format with links. Anyways I will update the question with a sample. Thanks

Comment: It looks like a standard [MIME encoded email](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME), where somebody has sent you a formatted email using HTML. That's what emails look like! Take the HTML portion and render it with an HTML engine (eg web browser or WebKit).

Comment: If you can provide an approach to convert all the emails received to SES to render to HTML, it would be  better. I only see the option of using a Lambda and if you can relate with an example it would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve the outcome, instead of converting the mails, store them to a S3 bucket and using a S3 trigger, invoke a Lambda function which forwards the mail content. To simplify the forwarding, I have used the NPM library [aws-lambda-ses-forwarder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-lambda-ses-forwarder), which does all the heavy lifting. Following code shows the logic for email forwarding.

```
var LambdaForwarder = require("aws-lambda-ses-forwarder");

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

var overrides = {
    config: {
        fromEmail: "<forwarded-email-address>",
        subjectPrefix: "",
        emailBucket: "ses-bucket",
        emailKeyPrefix: "emails/",
        forwardMapping: {
            "<received-email-address>": [
                "<your-email-address>"
            ]
        }
    }
};
LambdaForwarder.handler(event, context, overrides);
};
```

- forwarded-email-address - You will receive the email to your inbox from this address.
- received-email-address - You will be receiving the emails sent to this address forwarded by the Lamda to your inbox.
- your-email-address - Your email address which you want to receive the forwarded emails.

In addition, make sure, the Lambda function has the right permission to read from S3 and forward mails, using SES.